# SAMBA 4 CN with multiple spaces, cannot modify, delete but can view

Tags: ldap, samba

Samba with internal LDAP (not openLDAP) configured as AD-DC

I have contacts created using CN={name}
Contacts that have multiple spaces in the names cannot be edited, deleted or removed from their groups, for example:

```
DN: CN=My  Name,OU=Contacts,OU=Base,DC=Test,DC=Local
```

Using LDAP Admin, Apache Directory Studio or LDB on the server all fail to rename, delete or modify the entry.
ldbsearch finds the object, ldbedit can also find and show the entry for editing but refuses to modify the entry.

Doing

```
ldbrename -H sam.ldb 'CN=My  Name,OU=Contact,OU=Base,DC=Test,DC=Local' 'CN=My Name,OU=Contacts,DC=Test,DC=Local'
```

Returns entry does not exist!

Is there any way I can just delete these entries safely and recreate them?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Running

```
samba-tool dbcheck --reindex
```

fixed the problem. I had to run this on all DCs. I was then able to delete users in a normal fashion.